# Oracle Update from Select - same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update column date1 with  highest date from column  date2,date3,date4. 
I have select statement

```
SELECT GREATEST(
    COALESCE(date2, date3, date4),
    COALESCE(date3, date4, date2),
    COALESCE(date4, date2, date3)
)
FROM (
    SELECT date1,date2,date3,date4 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE date1 is not null and (date1 < date2 or date1 < date3 or date1 < date4);
```

But I do not know how to use it with update or merge ??

`+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      date1       |      date2       |      date3       |      date4       |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 2017-04-13 16:54 | 2017-04-13 16:57 |                  | 2016-06-16       |
| 2017-04-13 15:41 |                  | 2017-04-13 15:42 | 2016-06-16       |
| 2017-04-13 15:43 | 2018-01-10 14:23 | 2017-04-13 15:41 |                  |
| 2017-04-13 16:05 |                  | 2017-04-13 16:05 | 2016-06-16       |
| 2017-04-13 16:43 | 2017-04-13 16:43 |                  | 2016-06-16       |
| 2017-04-13 16:52 | 2017-04-13 16:52 | 2017-04-13 16:07 | 2017-04-17 16:07 |
| 2018-01-10 14:20 |                  | 2018-01-10 14:23 |                  |
| 2017-09-27 14:54 | 2015-09-08 09:56 | 2017-09-27 14:54 | 2015-03-13       |
| 2017-06-16 13:38 |                  | 2017-06-16 13:39 |                  |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+`

After update/merge I would like something like that

`+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      date1       |      date2       |      date3       |      date4       |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 2017-04-13 16:57 | 2017-04-13 16:57 |                  | 2016-06-16       |
| 2017-04-13 15:42 |                  | 2017-04-13 15:42 | 2016-06-16       |
| 2018-01-10 14:23 | 2018-01-10 14:23 | 2017-04-13 15:41 |                  |
| 2017-04-13 16:05 |                  | 2017-04-13 16:05 | 2016-06-16       |
| 2017-04-13 16:43 | 2017-04-13 16:43 |                  | 2016-06-16       |
| 2017-04-17 16:07 | 2017-04-13 16:52 | 2017-04-13 16:07 | 2017-04-17 16:07 |
| 2018-01-10 14:23 |                  | 2018-01-10 14:23 |                  |
| 2017-09-27 14:54 | 2015-09-08 09:56 | 2017-09-27 14:54 | 2015-03-13       |
| 2017-06-16 13:39 |                  | 2017-06-16 13:39 |                  |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
update t
    set date1 = greatest(date1, coalesce(date2, date1), coalesce(date3, date1), coalesce(date4, date1))
    where date1 < greatest(date1, coalesce(date2, date1), coalesce(date3, date1), coalesce(date4, date1));
```

In your data, `date1` appears to never be `NULL`.

Comment: The OP has `where date1 is not null` in his/her code, so presumably `date1` can be `null` (in the future if not today). But in that case your statement will update it to `null`, which is fine (it shouldn't be updated anyway), except it updates a row to itself, generally not an efficient option. You can improve this solution (which is excellent!) by adding a `where` clause which will then make the `update` as efficient as possible. Add: `where date1 < greatest(date1, coalesce(date2, date1), ...)` - same formula as in the `set` clause. +1 (and more if it were possible)

Comment: @mathguy . . . Given that the OP has that condition, it should be in the answer as well.

Comment: Right. What I suggested (which was different from `where date1 is not null`) would guarantee that `date1 is not null`, but it would also prevent `date1` from being updated to itself - especially important if the update should (otherwise) affect only a relatively small number of rows. The OP had the full `where` clause already, not just `date1 is not null`.