# SQL condition checking row elements

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm really new to sql / stackoverflow in general so bear with me.

I have a distinct select query that returns the following result

```
Name  Surname  Name2  Surname2  Status
----  -------  -----  --------  ------
Peter  Parker  Mary     Jane       0
Peter  Parker  Felicia  Hardy      1
Peter  Parker  Felicia  Hardy      0
Peter  Parker  Jonah   Jameson     1
```

So obviously every query will have different names. What I would like to show is
if the first person and second person have only one row, if it's 0 id like to show a finished message , if its 1 -> incomplete and if they have 2 rows (0 and 1) I'd like to show Working message.

```
Name  Surname  Name2  Surname2  Status
----  -------  -----  --------  ------
Peter  Parker  Mary     Jane    Finished
Peter  Parker  Felicia  Hardy   Working
Peter  Parker  Jonah    Jameson Incomplete
```

How should I go about this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: Another possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090871/oracle-update-from-select-same-table

Comment: Internet is filled with so many exemples and ways you could try to do this :) They do not answer the question directly but they give good hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when with aggregate function

```
    select Name,Surname,Name2,Surname2,
case when count( distinct Status) = 2 then 
         'Working' when sum(Status)=0 then 'Finished' else 'Incomplete'

       end  as status 
  from t
group by Name, Surname, Name2, Surname2;


NAME    SURNAME     NAME2   SURNAME2    STATUS
Peter   Parker      Mary    Jane         Finished
Peter   Parker      Felicia Hardy        Working
Peter   Parker     Jonah    Jameson      Incomplete
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
SELECT name, surname, name2, surname2, 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2 THEN 'Working'
        WHEN MAX(status) = 1 THEN 'Incomplete' 
        WHEN MAX(status) = 0 THEN 'Finished'
    END AS status
FROM table_name
--WHERE status IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY name, surname, name2, surname2
ORDER BY name, surname, name2, surname2;
```

Or this:

```
SELECT name, surname, name2, surname2, 
    CASE
        WHEN MIN(status) = 1 THEN 'Incomplete' 
        WHEN MAX(status) = 0 THEN 'Finished'
        ELSE 'Working'
    END AS status
FROM table_name
WHERE status IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY name, surname, name2, surname2
ORDER BY name, surname, name2, surname2;
```

If you only have 2 status `0` and `1` then ommit the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

You might use `group by Name, Surname, Name2, Surname2` with `avg(status)` options

```
select Name, Surname, Name2, Surname2, 
       ( case when avg(Status) = 1 then 
         'Incomplete'
         when avg(Status) = 0 then
         'Finished'
         else
         'Working'
       end ) as status 
  from tab
group by Name, Surname, Name2, Surname2;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4194/43)